# Wrong axis label while passing column name in ggplot function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

In the below example, I am passing a column name of a dataset into a function that uses ggplot. 
The function can extract the column name and successfully plot the graph but the axis label is wrong

```
library(tidyverse)
attach(mpg)

plot_func <- function(col_name) {
  ggplot(mpg,aes(x = col_name, fill = class)) +
    geom_bar() 
}

plot_func(drv)
```

[image: plot_function]

Is there anyway to change the x axis label from col_name to drv. I have tried the below, but it doesn't work.

```
plot_func("drv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `get()` in your function, so that it can be recognized as a variable in `aes(`), while being recognized as a character string in `xlab()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
attach(mpg)

plot_func <- function(col_name) {
  ggplot(mpg,aes(x = get(col_name), fill = class)) +
    geom_bar() +
    xlab(col_name)
}

plot_func("drv")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - but this approach still hasn't changed the x label to drv?

Answer (score 0):

Passing `drv` as a string works if you first change it to a symbol then unquote it.

```
library(tidyverse)
attach(mpg)

plot_func <- function(col_name) {
  col_name <- rlang::sym(col_name)
  ggplot(mpg,aes(x = !!col_name, fill = class)) +
    geom_bar() 
}

plot_func("drv")
```

Comment: Thank you! In my real dataset (not easy to provide a reproducible example), I get the following error: "Only strings can be converted to symbols" The field's datatype is a chr. Is there any reason why this happens?